# Shelly1 wiring 110v sw for buzzer along with door opener

Tags: home-automation

I’ve got shelly1 wired up to allow me to remotely open my door. I’m trying to see if I can use SW to detect the buzzer (along with a custom circuit). Here’s what I have without door buzzer detection:

```
Neutral - N
110 Hot - L
SW - so far unused
I - one side of door open button
O - other side of door open button
```

This works well.
I’m trying to figure out how to wire in a door buzzer press. I have a circuit to convert the door button press to a DC signal. But that signal is not related to 110 hot, so I’m stuck. Help appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are using a Shelly model that is UL-Listed. Things which are not safe or legal to be installed in North American AC mains wiring.

Comment: It is UL-Listed.

Answer (score 0):

Use your DC circuit to drive a relay. Then from relay you can control your sw pins.

Comment: OK. But for relay, can I input 110 Hot on one end, and other end to SW? If so, do you know the current that will flow? Do I need high gauge wire or will it be very low current as it's just used to detect connection?